# Need to pair values of objects from array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
boxes= [{"itemsId":19,"quantity":0},{"itemsId":1053,"quantity":1},{"itemsId":1056,"quantity":1}];
```

How to pair values of objects from array? 
Here's what I'd like boxes to look like:

```
boxes= [{"itemsId":quantity},{"itemsId":quantity},{"itemsId":quantity}];
```

ie.

```
boxes= [{"19":0},{"1053":1},{"1056":1}];
```

Comment: In your initial array, will you ever have two objects with the same `itemsId` and different `quantity`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In each iteration set the value of *itemsId* as the key and the value of *quantity* as the value for that key.

```js
var boxes= [{"itemsId":19,"quantity":0},{"itemsId":1053,"quantity":1},{"itemsId":1056,"quantity":1}];
boxes = boxes.map(i => ({[i.itemsId]:i.quantity}));
console.log(boxes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to return an array and inside the callback return an object.Use square notation to create the object key. Since object key is unique the new value will overwrite old value inside an object

```js
let boxes = [{
  "itemsId": 19,
  "quantity": 0
}, {
  "itemsId": 1053,
  "quantity": 1
}, {
  "itemsId": 1056,
  "quantity": 1
}];

let newData = boxes.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    [elem.itemsId]: elem.quantity
  }

});

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: No need to worry about unique keys in this case. i think

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var boxes = [{"itemsId":19,"quantity":0},{"itemsId":1053,"quantity":1},{"itemsId":1056,"quantity":1}];

var result = boxes.map(({itemsId, quantity}) => ({[itemsId]: quantity}))

console.log(result)
```